# Flux.just with delayElements works with Strings but not with Custom types

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to build a reactive REST endpoint with API returning Employee data(5 employees) with delay of 2 seconds each.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/strings", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Flux<Employee> getStringsStream() {
        return Flux.just(new Employee("Alok"),
                new Employee("Ashish"),
                new Employee("Neeraj"),
                new Employee("Shantanu"),
                new Employee("Gaurav")).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
    }
}

record Employee(String name) {}
```

It behaves like blocking API and takes total 2*5 = 10 seconds, and renders whole data at once.
While it works fine (proper reactively) if I just return Employee names (String) data. Data get rendered at 2 seconds for each name sequentially.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/strings", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Flux<String> getStringsStream() {
        return Flux.just("Alok",
                "Ashish",
                "Neeraj"
                ,"Shantanu",
                "Gaurav").delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
    }
```

I am new to reactive programming. Am I missing any concept here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different return types use different response encoders in Spring Webflux.

While `Flux<String>` will trigger `CharSequenceEncoder`, a `Flux` of custom Java objects like `Employee` will trigger `Jackson2JsonEncoder`. This results in different behaviour for the different return types.

As documented in [Spring Webflux reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs):

> The Jackson2Encoder works as follows:
>
> - For a single value publisher (e.g. Mono), simply serialize it through the ObjectMapper.
> - For a multi-value publisher with application/json, **by default collect the values with Flux#collectToList() and then serialize the
>   resulting collection**.
> - For a multi-value publisher with a streaming media type such as application/x-ndjson or application/stream+x-jackson-smile, encode,
>   write, and flush each value individually using a line-delimited JSON
>   format. Other streaming media types may be registered with the
>   encoder.
> - For SSE the Jackson2Encoder is invoked per event and the output is flushed to ensure delivery without delay.

As you can see the default behaviour is serializing it as a JSON array. However, you can customize the behaviour by specifying the `produces` attribute in the request mapping annotation. The following for example will achieve your desired behaviour:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/json-stream", produces = TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Employee> getJsonStream() {
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin. I will go through the docs. Thank you for the motivation.